# How can i debug aws lambda authorizer that is producing error with AuthorizerConfigurationException

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a AWS Lambda Authorizer which is Request Type, I pass sessionToken in headers and username in queryString Parameters in my Authorizer lambda functions
But it is giving me error of `{"errorMessage":"RequestId: 97d57a97-3baf-421f-aabc-88ed5f6dd4ef Process exited before completing request"}
Mon Sep 23 10:05:39 UTC 2019 : AuthorizerConfigurationException`

Here is my authorization lambda function code:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB({ region: 'ap-south-1', apiVersion: '2012-08-10' });

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    var userSessionToken = event.headers.sessionToken;
    var userEmailId = event.queryStringParameters.emailId;

    var tmp = event.methodArn.split(':');
    var apiGatewayArnTmp = tmp[5].split('/');
    var resource = '/';
    if (apiGatewayArnTmp[3]) {
        resource += apiGatewayArnTmp[3];
    }

    var authResponse = {};

    if (userSessionToken && userEmailId) {
        callback(null, validateUserSession(userSessionToken, userEmailId));
    }  else {
        callback("session token or email id is missing");
    }

const generatePolicy = (principalId, effect, resource) => {
    var authResponse = {};
    authResponse.principalId = principalId;
    if (effect && resource) {
        var policyDocument = {};
        policyDocument.Version = '2012-10-17'; // default version
        policyDocument.Statement = [];
        var statementOne = {};
        statementOne.Action = 'execute-api:Invoke'; // default action
        statementOne.Effect = effect;
        statementOne.Resource = resource;
        policyDocument.Statement[0] = statementOne;
        authResponse.policyDocument = policyDocument;
    }
    return authResponse;
}

const generateAllow = (principalId, resource) => {
    return generatePolicy(principalId, 'Allow', resource);
};

const generateDeny = (principalId, resource) => {
    return generatePolicy(principalId, "Deny", resource);
}

const validateUserSession = (userSessionToken, userEmailId) => {
    var params = {
        Key: {
            "username": {
                S: userEmailId
            },
            "sessionToken": {
                S: userSessionToken
            }
        },
        TableName: "mytable"
    };
    dynamodb.getItem(params, function(err, data) {
    if(err) {
        callback(null, generateDeny('user', event.methodArn));
    } else {
        let currentUnixTime = new Date().getTime();
        let sessionTime = data.Item.session_created_at.N;
        let isSessionExpired = (currentUnixTime - 900) < sessionTime;

        if(isSessionExpired){
            callback(null, generateDeny('user', event.methodArn));
        } else {
            callback(null, generateAllow('user', event.methodArn));
        }
    }
    });
}
};
```

Here I am querying dynamodb table with sessionToken and username if it exists and has lesser than 15 minutes before time I would like to give access otherwise not.
But when I test my authorizer It produces error

Answer (score 0):

When a Node.js Lambda reaches the end of the main thread, it ends all other threads.

Use `async` and `await` and the `.promise()` method to `await` the `dynamodb.getItem()` call:

```
exports.handler = async function(event, context, callback) {
    var userSessionToken = ...;
    ...
    var authResponse = ...;

    if (userSessionToken && userEmailId) {
        callback(null, await validateUserSession(userSessionToken, userEmailId));
    }  else {
        ...
    }

    ...

const validateUserSession = async (userSessionToken, userEmailId) => {
    var params = {
        ...
    }
    let data;
    try {
        data = await dynamodb.getItem(params).promise();
    } catch (err) {
        callback(null, generateDeny('user', event.methodArn));
    }
    let currentUnixTime = new Date().getTime();
    let sessionTime = data.Item.session_created_at.N;
    let isSessionExpired = (currentUnixTime - 900) < sessionTime;
    if(isSessionExpired){
        callback(null, generateDeny('user', event.methodArn));
    } else {
        callback(null, generateAllow('user', event.methodArn));
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are invoking the `callback` inside your `validateUserSession` function, you should not invoke it at the main handler logic. You can change the handler logic as follows to fix this.

```
...
if (userSessionToken && userEmailId) {
    validateUserSession(userSessionToken, userEmailId);
} else {
   callback("session token or email id is missing");
}
...
```